# Use threading and queues to redirect logger messages to tkinter widget in python

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, tkinter, message-queue

greetings to the community.
I am facing the following problem: I have a simple tkinter GUI with a button that launches a number of calculations while printing in a tkinter widget various messages related to the calculation's progress.

I have read a few posts and, from what I understand, the most efficient way is to create a queue in the main thread, bind the queue to a logger, run the calculations in a separate thread, and redirect its messages to the queue which is polled by the main thread using an interval.

But I am clearly doing something wrong. The messages are written in my scrolled frame widget but all at once after the threaded operation finishes.

Here is my code (I will simplify it as best as I can):

```
class GFTGUI(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.app = parent

        # create widget to store messages  
        logger_pane = ttk.PanedWindow(self.app, orient=VERTICAL)
        logger_pane.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S), padx=10, pady=10)
        self.logger_frame = ttk.Labelframe(logger_pane, text="Message Board")
        logger_pane.add(self.logger_frame, weight=1)

        self.scrolled_text = ScrolledText(self.logger_frame, state='disabled')
        self.scrolled_text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(N, S, W, E))
        self.scrolled_text.configure(font='TkFixedFont')

        # configure GUI logger
        ConfigureTkFrameLogger(self.logger_frame, self.scrolled_text, self.gft)

        # create the run button
        self.run_button = Button(self.gft, text="Run!", command=self.run_command, height=35)
        self.run_button.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=3, pady=4)

    def run_command(self): 
        th = threading.Thread(target=run_calculations)  # see final block of code
        th.start()
        th.join()

def start_gui():
    app = Tk()
    GFTGUI(app)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__': start_gui()
```

Then I have a separate file (called helpers.py) that stores the class for the logger:

```
logger_user = logging.getLogger('user')

class ConfigureTkFrameLogger:

    def __init__(self, logger_frame, scrolled_text):

        self.logger_frame = logger_frame
        self.scrolled_text = scrolled_text

        # Create a logging handler using a queue
        self.log_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.queue_handler = QueueHandler(self.log_queue)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%H:%M:%S')
        self.queue_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.queue_handler.set_name('gui')
        logger_user.addHandler(self.queue_handler)

        # Start polling messages from the queue
        self.logger_frame.after(100, self.poll_log_queue)

    # Check every 100ms if there is a new message in the queue to display
    def poll_log_queue(self):

       while True:
          try: record = self.log_queue.get(block=False)
          except queue.Empty: break
          else: self.display(record)

       self.logger_frame.after(100, self.poll_log_queue)

    def display(self, record):
        msg = self.queue_handler.format(record)
        self.scrolled_text.configure(state='normal')
        self.scrolled_text.insert(END, msg + '\n', record.levelname)
        self.scrolled_text.configure(state='disabled')
        self.scrolled_text.yview(END)  # Autoscroll to the bottom

class QueueHandler(logging.Handler):

   def __init__(self, log_queue):
       super().__init__()
       self.log_queue = log_queue

   def emit(self, record): self.log_queue.put(record)
```

Finally, my calculations are done in a method stored in a separate file:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('user')

def run_calculations(some_args...):

    # this message should be printed as soon as the calculations begin
    logger.info('Reading input file')
    
    do other stuff here
```

I think I am close in making it work. I just need a little push!

Comment: As you have called `join()` and it will block the application until the thread is completed.  So `app.mainloop()` (which handles all tkinter events and update) will be executed after all threads are completed and that is what you see.  You don't need to call `join()` in deed.

Comment: hm it worked. i have misjudged the use of join. i thought that join blocks the main thread in order for the main thread to finish after the thread not that it will block all operations in the main thread such as polling from the queue. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be a comment, but I "must have 50 reputation to comment", so.
Without looking at anything else, I see this:

```
th.start()
th.join()
```

Do not start & immediately join (== wait for thread to finish).

Comment: thanks but i do not actually understand what is the problem that you have identified. It starts the thread and wait for it to finish. why do you say "Di not start..."

Comment: What is the point of starting a separate thread of execution, if you want to immediately wait for it to finish? You might as well call the function (that you passed to the thread) directly. This way you are only making an unnecessary context switch, that you do not take advantage of.